# Control running Java SE program remotely

Tags: java, remote-access

I wrote Java SE program which has deal with really huge dataset of matrices(10^12 matrices). I am generating them through iterator and saving special ones (which satisfy some criteria) either to Java heap or database. So, I understand that it's gonna take a lot of time (probably a few days). In order to operate with all this stuff I decided to run the program on computer which is not at my apartment and has access to the Internet. I want to control runnig process of the program (for me is very important to know is everything OK with the program? Is the program still running?)

My question is how to control that my program is still running (for this purpose I want to use computer at my appartment and the Internet)?

Maybe my program should periodically post (via Java IO API ) messages to  websites ( Google Docs and so on). Thanks in advance for all your responses.

Comment: SSH I even don't know what is it? Can you provide a bit more information?

Comment: It's a method of getting terminal shell access on a remote machine, I recommend you google it. Using it you could use command line process management tools to communicate with your program.

Comment: Is it OS independent?

Comment: Although it's a unix tool, it is available for windows. See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/itdojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/3506 for info on how to set up a server on your machine. You can then connect to that ssh server with an ssh client such as Putty http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your application with `JPDA` enabled. This way you can connect it remotely, examine threads, etc.

`JPDA` has a number of other advantages as well, for example hot code replace.

[Specification for JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) is here, the most important is that you have to pass a few JVM options on startup, it will open a port, and you can use Eclipse or NetBeans to attach it from anywhere on the net. You have to make sure that the opened port is accessible through firewalls (local and network).

Comment: Thanks @GaborSch I'll explore it.

Comment: If you have low bandwidth between the two machines, this will not work efficiently, though.

Comment: Thank you @GaborSch. I think there are no problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

First you should try a remote desktop connection. [Here's link to MS documents for Windows 7 remote desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/connect-to-another-computer-using-remote-desktop-connection).

If the remote computer is Linux/Unix, and your program is console application, [ssh+screen](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh%20screen%20howto) is the old, true and tested solution to leave interactive console programs running and accessible from anywhere, while you frolic in the real world.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: So you can't enable Remote Desktop on the remote Win7 machine?

Comment: to be honest I've never been doing that I'll definetly try to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for VisualVM & remote JMX. Setup the server box to allow remote jmx connections. With VisualVM you'll be able to connect to the JVM and check the activity.

You can also set up MBeans to keep stats of the running process. Which you'll be able to check also with VisualVM.

Comment: Add this to the process of the server: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip of the server>

And you'll be able to connect with VisualVM.

Comment: The tutorial to MBeans - should you need something custom: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html